# Epizeuxis (畳語法) in Modern Japanese language

Tags: words

When I was reading English, I found this exotic word: **epizeuxis**.

[image]

Instantly I racked my brains to find the equivalent counterpart in Japanese.

Here are the results:

> [**Epizeuxis**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%95%B3%E8%AA%9E%E6%B3%95) : **畳語法** (じょうごほう)、 または畳句法、**畳音法**)

> [Kotobank Definition](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%95%B3%E8%AA%9E%E6%B3%95-292792): 同じ語句を繰り返して強調やリズムの効果を上げようとする修辞法。

Others definition:

> **《畳語法》**
>   畳語法（じょうごほう、または畳句法、畳音法、Epizeuxis）とは、激しさまたは強調のために、言葉を連続して繰り返す修辞技法のこと。

My Questions:

1. Is there any practical use of **Epizeuxis (畳語法)** in Japanese?
2. If there is one, can you give an example?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476592/word-for-repetition-of-a-same-word-before-and-after-comma#476592

Comment: As a total side comment, the phrase 'rack your brains' in English implies searching your own brain for information you already possess; this sounds instead like you had to go and do research to find the Japanese word.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, there is a practical use of **epizeuxis (畳語法)**.
2. Example:

[image]

**Text:**

> 大嫌い！！
>
> 大嫌い
>   大嫌い
>   大っ嫌いっ！！
>
> 嫌い
>   大っ嫌い！
>
> 大嫌い…
>
> 大っ嫌い！！

**Translation:**

> I really hate you !!
>
> really really hate
>
> really really hate
>
> really r..re..really h..ha..hate you !!
>
> hate you
>
> r..re..really hate you!
>
> I really hate you...
>
> I r..re..really hate you !!